# Is there a way to view/access the latest.log of a public minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft

I'm currently working on a bot for some anarchy servers, and it's a lot more reliable for it to read the log than just plain chat. I need a way to access that, but I don't know how. Is there even a way to do this without admin access?

Answer (score 0):

No there is actually no way to view this. Because it's a file located on the server you can only view it if you have (direct) file access to the server. The only way to get the latest.log file is to contact the server owner, but I think that no server owner of e.g Hypixel will give you this log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Minecraft plugin in Java that acts as an API server, you can then make it read the file and return it. Of course, you would want to protect it with some type of authorization. You can use an [HTTP server](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html), an example would be [this](https://github.com/FluxedScript/SmartStaff/blob/master/src/main/java/tk/ifutureserver/fluxedscript/smartstaff/webpanel/), it allows commands to be executed but you could easily work off that.

As MCTzOCK mentioned you can't view it without asking for permission from the server owner.